# Integrating a function "bit by bit"

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation, piecewise

I am trying to integrate a function. But for this task I need to do it 
"bit by bit". I created a working example that shows the problem.

```
pBF := 
  FunctionInterpolation[
    Piecewise[{{9890/3, 500 <= z <= 800}}], 
    {z, 0, 1300}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1];
dz = 1300/25;  
For[i = 1, i <= 25, i++,
  Sol = Integrate[pBF, {z, (i - 1) dz, i dz}]];
```

I don't get any output from the For-loop, so I'm assuming that either I have made a syntax error or that `Integrate` can't work that way. I really have to do this in a "bit by bit" way.

Comment: What do you mean by "[you] don't get any output"? As in no output appears despite evaluation completing? You are aware that `;` suppresses outputs in Mathematica?

Comment: Yes I'am aware of the " ; " at the end of the equation. But when I'm checking Sol afterwards. I get nothing so I'm assuming that there is no value stored in Sol ?

Comment: I swapped your `For` loop for a `Table` and I get an output now, but I think you have bigger problems:`pBF := FunctionInterpolation[Piecewise[{{9890/3, 500 <= z <=800}}], 
{z, 0, 1300}, InterpolationOrder->1];
dz = 1300/n;  

Table[Integrate[pBF, {z, (i - 1) dz, i dz}], {i, 1, 2}]
`

Comment: The way you have written it, `Sol` will be continuously overwritten at each step of the `For` loop. After the `For` loop executes, you will have `Sol = Integrate[pBF, {z, 24 dz, 25 dz}]`. The way it's written, there's really no point in have a `For` loop. If you would like the 25 results, you should use `Table`. Also, `n` is currently undefined so it's not possible to finish the calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is integrate the function, one piece at a time, you can try:

```
n = 25; (* number of chunks *)
pBF = FunctionInterpolation[
  Piecewise[{{9890/3, 500 <= z <= 800}}], 
  {z, 0, 1300}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1
];
data = Table[Integrate[pBF[z], {z, (i - 1) 1300/n, i 1300/n}], {i, n}];
Total[data]
ListPlot[
  Accumulate[data]
]
(* 977 668. *)
```

[image: Integral of poster's function.]

By summing the pieces, you can see that we approach the value of 977 668.

Comment: Thank you very much @MassDefect, this is exactly what I'm looking for.